# Why is a receiving circuit in e.g. RFID made resonant with a parallel capacitance instead of a series capacitance?

Tags: rfid, parallel, series, inductive, resonance

Take for example the schematic below of a inductive receiving circuit in RFID, where we want to maximize the voltage over the load resistor R4 (R3 is the resistance of the inductive coil, and the voltage source represents the signal that is received and induced in the coil)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMmfE6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The voltage is now V2*R4/(R3+sL1+R4), which in my opinion can easily be maximized by adding a series resonant capacitance, such that the impedance is real at resonance (and further maximized by increasing R4). However, I read that voltage maximization for circuits as this one is done by adding a parallel capacitance. When doing the calculations, I always obtain a voltage that is lower than the one for the simple series resonant circuit I present here.

EDIT: when considering the measuring device to have an infinite input impedance, the measured voltage for the series resonant circuit equals the applied voltage V2. For the parallel resonant circuit, it equals 1/(sRC) times the applied voltage V2. Is it possible that the eventual best solution is depending on the size of R and C and the operating frequency (whether their product is larger or smaller than 1)?

Answer (score 1):

That's because the model you are assuming does not well replicate an rfid receiver.

The EM wave that couples with the coil produces some varying voltage at the coil's terminals, so the voltage generator, with a series resistor if you want, should be in parallel with the coil. Now the best you can do is adding a parallel capacitor so that the LC parallel resonates at the right frequency provoking a very high **voltage** gain (**not** power gain).

Comment: Although intuitively it is weird, I thought that the effect of mutual coupling between two coils can be modelled as a series voltage source at the receiver, and a series impedance at the transmitter?

Answer (score 1):

The RFID receive coil is induced with a voltage from the transmit coil. This voltage is generated in series with the receive coil and, when you add a "so-called" parallel capacitor you are actually making a highly resonant LC low pass filter: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7slka.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It's still a series circuit but you are taking the voltage across the capacitor i.e. there can be very significant voltage amplification. We call it parallel thru laziness I suspect and I am as guilty of this as anyone.

Comment: If you add a series resistor to 'Coupled V' my parallel configuration is as good as yours, or not?

Comment: @VladimirCravero The voltage generator you mention can never be in parallel with the inductor with or without a series resistor. That bit is incorrect as I see it. I would also say that resonating can get more power - i've seen tuned LC coils producing a magnetic field totally "loaded" when a tuned coil is brought near them. If the coil were (say) just shorted the effect hardly could be seen until the coils got much closer.

Comment: can you explain why?

Comment: @VladimirCravero The voltage induced is in the coil and the amount of induced voltage is due to the coupling factor. The coupling factor (say 10%) is like having 10% of the windings bypassed and directly connected to the transmit voltage source whilst 90% of the receiver inductance left as uncoupled and therefore in series with the induced voltage.

Comment: As I wrote in the edit of my question: Is it possible that the eventual best solution is depending on the size of R and C and the operating frequency (whether their product is larger or smaller than 1)? I suppose that for strong overdamped LC-circuits, a "parallel" resonant capacitance is actually disadvantageous compared to a series resonant capacitance (although in that case the series capacitance may as well be left out)?

Comment: @BNJMNDDNN the voltage across the input circuit it feeds will be tuned to be very much higher than the induced voltage in the coil. Calling it series or parallel is just semantics. The point being that it magnifies the voltage by several times (Q dependent) - lowering R (series R) is the key to obtaining a bigger Q.

Comment: @Andyaka I am considering a low inductance coil with a high intrinsic series resistance which cannot be lowered, such that omega*L/R<1. I am not talking semantics now, but whether the capacitance is put in parallel or in series with the input circuit (R4 in my drawing). I understand that when putting it in parallel, a series RLC circuit is created and the voltage over R4 equals the voltage over this C (which normally is very large in a tuned RLC circuit). My question is that if omega*L/R<1, a "parallel" capacitance is actually disadvantageous.

Comment: It's on the cusp I'd say. Best idea o can think of is use LTSpice to simulate it. Why are you wanting to make the inductance low because the coupled voltage will be smaller and that confuses me.

Comment: Ok thank you; I have simulated it, but found it weird that I never found a reference in which people say that if the Q factor is below 1, making it resonant is actually disadvantageous (since RFID consders typically kinda small inductances too, compared to e.g. transformes, and their resistance is quite high because of the small thickness)